# Will a linearized dynamical system be stabile when using it with Euler's Method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, simulation, eulers-method

Assume that we have a dynamical system $\dot x = f(x, u)$ and I want to simulate the system with Euler's Method.

$$x = x + af(x, u)$$

Where $a$ is a small number. This can create unstability. What if I linearize the dynnamical system $\dot x = f(x, u)$ in the point $x$ and then simulate (I think this is the correct way to write the linearized $\dot x = f(x, u)$ )

$$x = x + a\frac{\partial f(x, u)}{\partial x}$$

Will the dynamical simulation with euler's method be secure against unstability?

Comment: The transformed system gives different solutions than the original system. /// What do you understand under "stability" and "linearization"? Note that taking the partial derivative is not linearization, it is using the corresponding linear Taylor polynomial.

Comment: @LutzLehmann So what should I do if I want to linearize $f(x, u)$ in $x$ ?

Comment: I assume you mean a numerical instability, i.e. a problem of the integration method, not the ODE itself. Note that the linearization does not necessarily fix this. 
The linearization must refer to all inputs, so also $u$, and include $f(x_0, u_0)$ (where $(x_0, u_0)$ is the linearization point).

Comment: @haavbj Yes! I have some issues with euler-metod when I simulate my ODE. Instead ODE45 in MATLAB works way much better...but much slower too. :( So if I linearize this ODE, then it won't give me any garanties of stability when I simulate? So...what should I do if I want to simulate an ODE and I care more about stability and speed than accuracy?

Comment: This really depends on the function $f$ and its inputs. Consider posting this too. If the system is stable, but the explicit methods (which Euler and ODE45 are) do not work well, the problem may have stiffness, so then perhaps an implicit method works better (like ode15s in Matlab).

Comment: @haavbj If the system is stable, then it will be stable for all inputs and trajectories?

Comment: @DanM well, it depends on what you mean by claiming "the system is stable", this will have many nuances.

Comment: @haavbj Ok, let's explain my goal then: I want to have a fast and stable simulation of an ODE. The accuracy is not important here. The problem is that the Euler simulation is not so stable due to non adaptive step size. But Euler simulation is fast. The problem is that ODE45 is slow but ODE45 is more stable due to adaptive stepsize. Also ODE45 have an accuracy that are way to much that I requries. I gave then two ways to solve this: 1. Either I compute if the ODE is stable or not for all X, if no = don't simulate. 2. Or I try to implement adaptive step size for euler method.

Comment: @haavbj If you want to simulate an ODE, very fast and make sure it's stable. What should you do if accuracy is not important for you? Which method should you use?

Comment: @DanM Still, your problem is kind of vague. If you have a stable *system*, but experience *numerical instability*, then as I said, you likely need an implicit method. Implicit Euler is fine, or try ODE15s as I already said. What is your notion of stability? Describe **the actual problem** in more detail in the original post.